# cronjob not working, but working in browser

Tags: apache, curl, cron

So I have this weird behaviour:

A customers runs an `oxid`-shop. He bought a module and in its documentation, it stated:

> Add 3 cronjobs: < url >

So, nothing too special so far. I tried it in the browser and everything worked fine. My output was:

```
Convert complete! 0 articles. File: google.xml
```

So the Script seems to work. Then I tried to combine it with a cronjob.

```
*/02 * * * * curl http://www.example.org/index.php?cl=param1&fnc=param2&rto=param3
```

as you can tell, a complete valid url (no special chars or something like this in the vars)

However, the output is the following:

**Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "" in /usr/www/users/.../www2/core/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094**

I also tried it with `lynx -dump URL`. Same output. I can't modify the script, since it is encrypted.

Any idea what I could try? Might the be due to the params? 
Tried it on 2 different servers with the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could in deed be that there are parameters in your URL.

> When using [] or {} sequences when invoked from a command line prompt,
>   you probably have to put the full URL within double quotes to avoid
>   the shell from interfering with it. This also goes for other
>   characters treated special, like for example '&', '?' and '*'.

*Source: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html*

So you should try to enclose your URL with double quotes.

Comment: That, good Sir, was indeed the problem. Working like a charme now, thank you :)